litellm.BadRequestError: LLM Provider NOT provided. Pass in the LLM provider you are trying to call
I'm getting the following error:

ERROR: LiteLLM call failed: litellm.BadRequestError: LLM Provider NOT
provided. Pass in the LLM provider you are trying to call. You passed
model=model='models/gemini-1.5-flash'
google_api_key=SecretStr('**********') temperature=0.5
client=<google.ai.generativelanguage_v1beta.services.generative_service.client.GenerativeServiceClient
object at 0x00000179649639D0> default_metadata=()  Pass model as E.g.
For 'Huggingface' inference endpoints pass in
completion(model='huggingface/starcoder',..) Learn more:
https://docs.litellm.ai/docs/providers

I am using Gemini 1.5 Flash and all the API keys are correct, but still it keeps showing and I am unable to resolve it. All the model configurations are correct.
I was trying to build agents using CrewAI and then run them. The model defined was Gemini 1.5 Flash, and the tool used was the SerperDevTool. Instead of executing the crew, it shows that the liteLLm is unable to find the LLM provider, and the execution stops.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you encounter this error, follow these two steps:

Use the CrewAI LLM class, which leverages LiteLLM in the background.
Make sure to set the LLM provider before configuring the LLM.

For Google AI Studio, use gemini/<LLM name>.
from crewai import Agent, LLM

my_llm = LLM(
    api_key=os.getenv("GEMINI_API_KEY"),
    model="gemini/gemini-1.5-flash",
),

my_agent = Agent(
    ...,
    llm=my_llm,
)

Here are all the major LLM providers, as of today:

OpenAI: <LLM name> (Note: You don't have to set the LLM provider.)
Azure OpenAI: azure/<your deployment name>
Azure AI Studio: azure_ai/<LLM name>
Anthropic: anthropic/<LLM name>
Mistral API: mistral/<LLM name>
Codestral API: codestral/<LLM name>
Hugging Face: huggingface/<LLM name>
Ollama: ollama/<LLM name>
Groq: groq/<LLM name>
Vertex AI: vertex_ai/<LLM name>
Gemini Google AI Studio: gemini/<LLM name>
AWS Sagemaker: sagemaker/<your endpoint name>
AWS Bedrock: bedrock/<LLM name>
Cohere: cohere/<LLM name>
Anyscale: anyscale/<LLM name>
Databricks: databricks/<LLM name>
Together AI: together_ai/<LLM provider>/<LLM name>
Replicate: replicate/<LLM name>
Fireworks AI: fireworks_ai/<LLM name>
Predibase: predibase/<LLM name>
Nvidia NIM: nvidia_nim/<LLM provider>/<LLM name>
IBM watsonx.ai: watsonx/<LLM provider>/<LLM name>
LiteLLM Proxy (LLM Gateway): litellm_proxy/<LLM name>

In case of an error or if you want to see the full list, please refer to the LiteLLM Providers page.

I faced the same problem when I was adding the model in LiteLLM using UI.
I got this error when I added the model using 'Add new model' screen as:
Public Model Name= llama:latest
LiteLLM Model Name(s) = llama

It got fixed when I changed it to:
Public Model Name= llama
LiteLLM Model Name(s) = ollama/llama

After this change the health check and test key, both are good.
